# Neo4j Transferring All Data from Postgres

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4jclient, neo4jrestclient

I'm attempting to transfer all data over to Neo4j, and am wondering if it would be alright to name all properties on nodes the same as in Postgres exactly. E.g id will be id, name will be name, and so on. Are there any conflicts with doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, especially if you use the one of the clients to do the migration as they will automatically escape anything that needs to be escaped, but there's nothing I've come across.